# How do you create a Hight Charts chart that updates every second with real data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Is there a way to create a chart that updates every second with real data like this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/)?
I couldn't figure it out. I basically want a chart that updates every second with data in the past. I updated a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32HEu/1/) with my data but couldn't get it to work.

Every example I found online deals with random data but I can't figure out how to use my data instead of random.

I know it has something to do with this part of the code:

```
events: {
    load: function() {

      // set up the updating of the chart each second
      var series = this.series[0];
      setInterval(function() {
      var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
      y = Math.random();
      series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the line `y = Math.random();` does? *That* is the point you would fill in your data.

Comment: How can I get the data in y and x? series.x and series.y doesn't work

Comment: What does `data in the past mean`?  Where is **your** data?

Comment: I have data here: http://jsfiddle.net/32HEu/1/  see categories and data.  Basically I am showing counts for every hour for the past 3 days and I want it to look like the real time chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my changes for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/KXpF7/3/

First, your data format is wrong since it's one dimension only, cannot be used to present (x,y)

```
data: [[3,11,0,3,4,40,2,11,1,5,40,12,11,40,1,40,12,2,3,2,1,12,1,0,1,15,1,4,12,0,4,5,4,12,15,12,1,2,12,2,3,10,4,15,5,4,12,11,0,15,4,40,4,15,1,4,4,40,12,15,1,0,0,5,11,12,15,0,2,4,11]]; // wrong format
```

You can have an array to put all of your historical data in a [x,y] format, which you can use in both categories in xAxis and series declaration.

```
var historicalData = [['2013-11-20 15:00:00',3],['2013-11-20 16:00:00',11],['2013-11-20 17:00:00',0],['2013-11-20 18:00:00',3],['2013-11-20 19:00:00',4],['2013-11-20 20:00:00',40],['2013-11-20 21:00:00',2],['2013-11-20 22:00:00',11],['2013-11-20 23:00:00',1],['2013-11-21 00:00:00',5],['2013-11-21 01:00:00',40]]; // finish the rest data by yourself
```

In the beginning you show the first N data points of historicalData. (modify `var defaultDataNum = 5;` according to your need)

```
        series: [{
            name: 'Real data',
            data: (function() {
                var data = [];
                // display the first defaultDataNum points in the beginning
                for (var i = 0; i < defaultDataNum; i++) {
                    data.push(historicalData[i]);
                }
                return data;
            })()
        }]
```

And get one more point from historicalData to display every 1 second afterwards.

```
        var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            series.addPoint(historicalData[currentDataPos], true, true);
            currentDataPos++;
            // stop update when finish display all data
            if(currentDataPos == historicalData.length)
               clearInterval(intervalId);
        }, 1000);
```

That's the basic idea, please refer to my jsfiddle for all the details.